# Rails: Does every http request creates a new connection pool?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection-pooling

i am reading this article https://polycrystal.org/posts/2012-05-25-active-record-connection-pool-fairness.html and it states that every http reuest create a new connection pool. is it true??

If it is true then what if a http request creates two threads that needs to access database then will that two threads create two separate connection pool agian or they will use the connection pool created by a http request.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not request, but every worker process. The whole concept of connection pooling is to eliminate the need for establishing a db connection in every request.

Comment: so if there are two worker process then there will be two connection pools??

Comment: Does all application server supports concept of worker process??